# Entering an external input while using python selenium

Tags: python, function, selenium, input

I would like to write a python selenium script which works as follows:

```
 my_python_selenium_function.py <-- inputvar1, inputvar2
```

It will simply use **my_python_selenium_function.py** file as a function and use `inputvar1` and `inputvar2` while I am trying to use those variable in my python selenium file to provide what my python file does. Does any one have an idea about how I can make this ?

Samet

Comment: If you're talking about giving command-line arguments to python file, you can do it with argparse.

Comment: Make sense. I'll look through argparse. I am simply trying this python script on  bash script. By giving `chmod 777 my_bash_script.sh` , then using like `./my_bash_script.sh input1 input2` is giving almost what I want. But, this does not work for python script. Does `argparse` provide the same methodology ?

Comment: So you want something like.. ./my_python.py option1 optiontwo, and assign optionone and optiontwo to variables?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

It looks like want to supply arguments to your python file.
You can do it in numerous ways.

Here is an approach that uses `sys` module and works with the file arguments.

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[0]
one = sys.argv[1]
two = sys.argv[2]
three = sys.argv[3]
print 'You are running '+filename
print one+' '+two+' '+three
```

On running this file on the terminal, like:

```
$ python arg.py hello world "i am learning python!"
```

the command will return:

```
You are running arg.py
hello world i am learning python!
```

I hope you got the idea what you'll need to implement.

For complex arguments and options, it is recommended to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).